# Extraer 9 digitos(telefono) de una cadena de texto PHP

Tags: php, regex

Podrian apoyarme a realizar esto: Tengo un texto en la cual se encuentra un numero de 9 digitos y lo necesito extraer para almacenarlo en una variable:

Ejemplo de la cadena de texto :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. Integer ac tempor 123456789, et semper arcu. Maecenas vitae enim sed tortor 980202301 venenatis commodo. Fusce tincidunt volutpat bibendum. Cras vehicula ligula at urna vestibulum condimentum.

Praesent non blandit 45678910911, sed porta nulla. Phasellus eleifend, metus in consequat dictum, arcu nibh accumsan dolor, eget tristique eros massa et nisl. Anexo 4577 Phasellus congue consequat ante, nec  nisi sed elit malesuada tempor
```

Los numeros que necesito siempre empiezan con 9 de inicial y no siempre se encuentran en la posicion 1 o 2 es aleatoria, el codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente :

```
$str = "Lorem...";
$pattern = '/[0-9]{9}/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)){
echo $matches[0];
}
```

El resultado que me arroja es el siguiente : 123456789
Lo correcto seria: 980202301

Comment: Codigo ?? o adivinamos que sucede acá ?

Comment: La expresión regular sería `"\d{9}"`, el código ya lo escribes tú (yo no sé php)

Answer (score 0):

bueno mira primero debemos saber usar funciones  en php : [Click aqui para ver el link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.user-defined.php)

Podemos usar la función incorporada preg_match_all() para extraer números de una string. Esta función busca globalmente un patrón especificado de una string. La sintaxis correcta para usar esta función es la siguiente:

```
> preg_match_all($pattern, $inputString, $matches, $flag, $offset);
```

La función incorporada preg_match_all() tiene cinco parámetros. Los detalles de sus parámetros son los siguientes

[image: Parametros preg_match_all()]

Esta función devuelve una variable booleana. Devuelve true si el patrón dado existe.

El siguiente programa muestra cómo podemos usar la función preg_match_all() para extraer números de una cadena dada.

```
<?php $string = 'Sarah has 4 dolls and 6 bunnies.';preg_match_all('!\d+!',string,$matches);print_r($matches); ?>
```

Hemos usado el patrón !\d+! para extraer números de la cadena.

Resultado:

Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
        )

)
```

Existen otras formas de hacerlo como usar la función filter_var() para extraer números de una cadena en PHP o usar la función preg_replace() para extraer números de una cadena, en fin, espero que te sea de ayuda!